# How to insert zlib data to Mongo? (Unicode issue)

Tags: python, mongodb, unicode, zlib

In python, I want to insert the output from zlib.compress to Mongo.

However, I get the following error:

"strings in documents must be valid UTF-8"

My understanding was the Mongo could handle byte-strings. How do I insert compressed data into the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use pymongo's [`pymongo.binary.Binary`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.5.1/api/pymongo/binary.html#pymongo.binary.Binary) class to wrap your binary compressed data so that it's not treated as a string.

Comment: Or mongoengine.fields.BinaryField if you are using MongoEngine

Comment: and how can I revert this?